# Why can't I access some methods for LinkedLists as specified in oracle's documentation?

Tags: java

```
List<Student> studentQueue = new LinkedList<>();

public void add(Student s){
    studenQueue.add(s);
    studentQueue.peek(); //Here i'm not getting a peek method as listed in the java API

}
```

As you can see for the peek method, it is define as a valid method in the Java API as specified at oracle's website. But when I try to use the method in practice, my IDE can't find that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `studentQueue` is `List<Student>`, 
and the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface doesn't have a `peek` method.
If you need to access the methods of `LinkedList`, then declare its type as such:

```
LinkedList<Student> studentQueue = new LinkedList<>();
```

For the record, in practice it's rare that you would need to rely on methods of a specific implementation. It's more common that the higher level design can depend on the more general `List<T>` interface (or even `Collection<T>` or `Iterable<T>`). Then you declare the most general interface that is necessary by the rest of the program, for example `List`, and and choose an appropriate implementation, for example `LinkedList` or `ArrayList`.

In short, if users of the `studentQueue` really need the methods of a `LinkedList`, then declare as a `LinkedList`, otherwise stick to the more general interface `List`.

Comment: why not casting instead?

Comment: Casting is ugly. And you have to make sure that you have the right type. You sacrifice simple type safety guaranteed by the compiler.

Comment: but programming to interfaces is a better practice dont you think?

Comment: The right interface to program to depends on what you want to do. If a `List` is good enough for your purpose, you should of declare a `List`. If you need a specific implementation, then it's better to declare that than cast.

Answer (score 0):

The available methods is base on the declaration type of the variable(`List` in your case).

To have acces at the peek method, you have to change the type of your variable to `LinkedList`

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because your reference variable is of type List. If you see the documentation for List Interface you will find that there is no peek() method.

It will work if you change the type of your reference variable to LinkedList.

Comment: Thanks for your input!